# Show co-ordinates on google map in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cllocationcoordinate2d

I am getting the co-ordinates from my json api

```
Alamofire.request(Constants.API.url("api/trip/"mykey"/startTrip"), method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
        self.progressHUD.dismiss(afterDelay: 0.5)
        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            guard let json = response.result.value as! [String:Any]? else{ return}
            guard let response = json["response"] as! [String:Any]? else{ return}
            guard let endCoordinates = response["end_coordinates"] as? [CLLocationDegrees] else { return }
            print(endCoordinates)
            guard let startCoordinates = response["start_coordinates"] as? [CLLocationDegrees] else { return}
            print(startCoordinates)

            let markerStart = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: startCoordinates[0] , longitude: startCoordinates[1] ))
            print(markerStart)
            markerStart.map = self.mapView

            let markerEnd = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: endCoordinates[0] , longitude: endCoordinates[1] ))
            markerEnd.map = self.mapView
            print(markerEnd)
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print("error")
            break

        }
    }
```

but I am unable to show it on the google maps. Honestly I don't know how can I show my co-ordinates on google maps?. Any Help?

[image]
//getting co-ordinates in postman

[image]

Comment: You want to add a marker or show in `UILabel`?

Comment: I want to add marker between start and end co-ordinates

Comment: your endCoordinates is an array of what?

Comment: above I show the postman data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your array of strings coordinates in `CLLocationCoordinate2D` coordinates and create both markers and assign them to your `GMSMapView`

**Code**

```
Alamofire.request(Constants.API.url("api/trip//startTrip"), method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
        self.progressHUD.dismiss(afterDelay: 0.5)
        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            guard let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] else{ return}
            guard let response = json["response"] as? [String:Any] else{ return}
            guard let endCoordinates = response["end_coordinates"] as? [CLLocationDegrees] else { return }
            print(endCoordinates)
            guard let startCoordinates = response["start_coordinates"] as? [CLLocationDegrees] else { return}
            print(startCoordinates)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let markerStart = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: startCoordinates[0], longitude: startCoordinates[1])) 
                markerStart.map = self.mapView 

                let markerEnd = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: endCoordinates[0], longitude: endCoordinates[1])) 
                markerEnd.map = self.mapView 
             }

        case .failure(_):
            print("error")
            break

        }
    }
```

Comment: ok @viper is normal because my code was not tested, can you post which are the errors?

Comment: Sir I added the screenshot and one more error Cannot convert value of type 'NSArray' to expected argument type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'

Comment: Sir I am getting this error Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CLLocationCoordinate2D and when I am using your code it shows red dot to change code

Comment: Sorry @viper check one last time and let me know, now this code was tested

Comment: everything okay sir Now I am getting only one error this Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'

Comment: check my last updated code, remove the previous one @viper

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170228/discussion-between-viper-and-reinier-melian).

Comment: Folks, please learn to read JSON. Both coordinates are clearly `[Double]`, all values are **not** in double quotes.

Comment: You are right @vadian I had updated my answer, I was talking with the OP in chat

Comment: @ReinierMelian `CLLocationDegrees` is a type alias of `Double`. You can avoid the entire cast / create dance (4 lines) if you optional downcast `guard let endCoordinates = response["end_coordinates"] as? [CLLocationDegrees] else { return }`

Comment: ok @vadian thanks again, my answer was edited I hope solves the issue from the OP

Comment: Everything is okay I am not getting errors anymore but marker is not showing on google maps. Any help?

Comment: I used that code infact location is printing on console but not in maps

Comment: I had updated my code again, now I had added DispatchQueue.main I think your problem is related to background thread of callback in alamofire @viper please try with this updated code

Comment: ok, add `debugPrint(markerStart.position)` below this line `markerStart.map = self.mapView ` @viper and let me know what prints